# Create common storyboard scene xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

When using story boards for `iOS` development, how would you create a common background for every scene?  As far as I can tell, I have to copy and paste common elements for every new scene.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in InterfaceBuilder, but [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) seems like it's designed for this sort of thing. Google it or check out [WWDC 2011 session 114](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=114).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BaseViewController and add your common details for all other VCs in it programmatically and derive all other VCs from the same.